# Multi-functional Shiny App Using Maps and Graphs

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to develop a Shiny App in R for a project that I am working on in order to more efficiently share data and display results of this data for a large working group. I have a spreadsheet with 75 trailheads (points) that contain information related to latitude, longitude, and visitor usage data based on month and year starting in 2016. What I am hoping to do is develop an app that allows users to select all or multiple trailheads and either display the count numbers based on a selected month of a year or a year and have those results be displayed on a map as points based on density as well as a graphical plot that will display the results of the trailheads on a bar graph or something similar that users can look at the geographical dispersion of usage as well as usage trends.

I am have gone through many examples but cannot seem to find any that would allow all this functionality. If anyone can point me in the right direction, as far as locating code, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at leaflet? This example app seems to offer similar functionality to what you've described: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html

Comment: Here is a Shiny Leaflet app that I created (apologies on shameless plug) that includes similar functionality.  https://petedunham.com/shiny/Interactive_Ohio_BirthData/ the source code is here: https://github.com/dunhampa/Interactive_Ohio_BirthData